# Connect to database robot framework failing to connect

Tags: database, robotframework

I have downloaded Databse library as well as pymssql module to connect to db that is used company wide.

I have tried the below code but receiving error

<[FAIL (+0.23s)] OperationalError: (18456, b"Login failed for user 'FORDVRANA4'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (phy310082l.pp.f01.dc1.ford.com)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (phy310082l.pp.f01.dc1.ford.com)\n")
Validate DB                                                           | FAIL |
OperationalError: (18456, b"Login failed for user 'FORDVRANA4'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (phy310082l.pp.f01.dc1.ford.com)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (phy310082l.pp.f01.dc1.ford.com)\n")>

---

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     DatabaseLibrary

*** Variables ***
${DBName}       DBname(used actual name in my code)
${DBUser}       Username(used actual name in my code)
${DBPassword}   None
${DBServer}     servername(used actual name in my code)
${DBPort}       1433


*** Test Cases ***
Validate DB
  Connect DB
  Disconnect From Database


*** Keywords ***
Connect DB
  Connect To Database     pymssql     ${DBName}   ${DBUser}   ${DBPassword}   ${DBServer}   ${DBPort}>
```

Comment: Did you do what the error suggests: "Check messages from the SQL Server"? The login is failing so you probably have a wrong username or password. Also, your code lists a pasword of `None` (the four bytes `N`, `o`, `n`, `e`. Is that really the correct password?

Comment: Just in case, could you check in addition to Bryan's points:
The end of the connect string above has a suspicious '>' character, e.g.,  ```  ${DBPort}>``` .   Should it be there?